# How to setup .htaccess to remove folder name and index.php from URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting

I have a URL of my website which uses Codeigniter Framework.
http://www.example.com/Sports/field/football/index.php/user/login
User is the controller and login the function

I want to remove the folders and index.php via .htaccess file and make it similar to the below
The user/login section will be dynamic and can be something else as well.

http://www.example.com/Sports/user/login

As of now I only have the below lines which only removes the index.php.
How do I implement the same?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: try to change default index page url in config.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?field/football/controller/function/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /controller/function [NC,R,L]
```

hope this can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. Place your .htaccess file in root folder.
2. Update your htaccess file,

   Change last line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]` with this code below

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
3. Open config.php and modify the code with given below:

   $config['index_page'] = "";

   $config['base_url'] = '';